# Include geographic information in user summary

Tags: feature-request

Each post or question has a small box that shows the user's avatar, name, reputation, and badge count. It would be great if geographic location was included. The level of detail would be up to the user according to things like size of country, climate area, personal privacy preferences,etc.

This information is irrelevant for most stackexchange sites, but is very useful here. many users are putting their location or climate in the questions, but it would be useful to include it automatically for times when we forget. Readers can also quickly see the location without having to re-scan the text looking for it.

Comment: How are things in Irving, TX?   :)   There's already location information on the user profile, if people choose to fill it out correctly.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't appear in the little box(eg. Above where my picture is)

Comment: IMO, people wouldn't necessarily know the climate of the asker's location. He would probably want to specify the climate anyway if it was important to the question.

Comment: I think this would still be useful.  Especially if could be linked to a feature to show the zone.

Comment: Add this feature please.

Comment: Well in the past few days we've started to get a lot of public beta users. Excellent as we're getting a wider mix of questions; but I (and others) are beginning to sound like broken records in the comments as we have to ask climate/condition/location type questions. Most people are forgetting to include it in the question even when it is very relevant.

Answer (score 17):

I don't agree. If the location is important to the question, **that information should be included in the text of the question itself** — or edited into the question, if it is missing. Displaying that information automatically for "times when we forget" could actually cause users to exclude that information from the question *explicitly*.

We resist features which make this system too much about WHO is asking the question. This site is about building an archive of knowledge for others who search out these questions. If this system starts to depend on the context of WHO is asking (rather than WHAT is being asked), the questions becomes *less* useful to those who come after. Consider:

- People move
- Users may choose to later "go private" by removing or changing that information
- A question can be copied under [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

Yikes! Can you see the difference between this …

> #### When should I start my tomatoes in Central Florida?
>
> [image: Robert Cartaino]
>
> #### 1 Answer
>
> Plant your seeds in mid-January. The second easiest season is Autumn. You can also grow tomatoes during the Winter if you are willing to cover them.

and this? …

> #### When should I start my tomatoes?
>
> [image: Robert Cartaino]
>  <sup><strike>Central Florida</strike>  St. Cloud, Minnesota</sup>
>
> #### 1 Answer
>
> Plant your seeds in mid-January. The second easiest season is Autumn. You can also grow tomatoes during the Winter if you are willing to cover them.

I would contend that the user's [flair](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/) is there to give that user a bit of notoriety and recognition… ***NOT* to add information to the question.**

Comment: -1 - I disagree with this completly, you resist to make a change to make it easier on the end user?  I frequently find myself asking the originator of the question where they are from.  Most people will STILL add the climate and where they are from so its just a backup.  Why not have it there, that way I can answer with: "Hello Joe Smoe, being that you are from Orlando, FL here is what I recommend".  Instead i have to rely on the end user stating the SAME information twice(once on the profile and once in the question).

Answer (score 2):

I would have liked to know where a person was coming from when they asked for a weed ID.

Telling a person from the UK that they've got Pigweed growing in their back yard, then editing their post to add North America to the question title makes me look like a doofus.  But that may have just been because I assumed that I was right ;-).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest adding a location field for questions. There are questions where the location would be continent (North America, Europe, Asia) since that is the relevant data regarding pests, and there are questions where it would be climate (aridity, temperature, humidity) for plant-growing issues. One user could have different "locations" for his hometown depending on the type of question.

Comment: This would still not provide sufficient detail for all questions. http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1098/ -- we need to know the lawn is under a covered area. http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1097/ -- geography is irrelevant. http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/987/ -- Central Valley is usually hot & dry, but the asker included the detail that this spring was cool and rainy. **The necessary details must be in the question, and we'll have to ask clarifying questions if they are left out.** There is no form or field that will magically force good questions.